# SSRS showing a blank column on a column grouping that is not in the design tab

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently trying to figure out why a blank new column is being added to my report. In the design tab, this column is not showing.

Please see screenshot below for the design tab:

[image]

The I'm using a column grouping here:
[image]

This is the output that I get when running the report:

[image]

Data behind this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and have anyway to remove this?

I've read that one guy added a column to the left and right outside of the group, then set this to hidden but didn't work for me here.

Any tips are much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have any blank or NULL values in the ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_DESC column of your dataset query results?

Comment: Check ALL your column header placeholders and see if there are any line breaks after those placeholders. If one column has a line break it will expand the entire row

Comment: Hi Alan , no, no nulls, just the data that I have attached. Bit of a mystery for me this

Comment: a mystery indeed... Not sure what to try next. Maybe create a new matrix as simple as possible and see if you still see it, if you do then it's got to be data. Also, change the column header background colour in the column group only so you can be sure its an additional column grouping.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan, there were some blanks in my dataset further down that I've now dealt with. Lesson learnt I guess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - There were some blank fields in my `Attribute_Group_Desc` column in my dataset which caused the blank column at the start within the matrix.

I've since dealt with my adding a clause on my SSRS report to hide the column, if the field `isNothing`. Similar to the below.

```
=iif(isNothing(Fields!Attribute_Group_Desc.value), True, False)
```

Hope this is helpful for the next person who has trouble with this.